# Split stacked entities using regex re.split in python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am having trouble splitting continuous strings into more reasonable parts:

E.g. 'MarieMüller' should become 'Marie Müller'

So far I've used this, which works if no special characters occur:

```
' '.join([a for a in re.split(ur'([A-Z][a-z]+)', ''.join(entity)) if a])
```

This outputs for e.g. 'TinaTurner' -> 'Tina Turner', but doesn't work
for 'MarieMüller', which outputs: 'MarieMüller' -> 'Marie M \utf8 ller'

Now I came accros using regex \p{L}:

```
 ' '.join([a for a in re.split(ur'([\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]+)', ''.join(entity)) if a])
```

But this produces weird things like: 
'JenniferLawrence' -> 'Jennifer L awrence'

Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Can you install an additional module? Python's built-in [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is very limited; you need the [`regex` module (PyPI)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) for your second regex to work.

Comment: a lot simpler way to do this will be `re.sub(r'(?=(?!^)[A-Z])', ' ', x, re.UNICODE)`

Comment: You are using Python 2, aren't you?

Comment: This actually works quite good, would you mind explaining why ?=(?!^)[A-Z])' works?

Comment: Are you using python3 or python2?

Comment: python 2.7. And one more thing, I would like to avoid stop splitting after a lower case is followed by an upper one, at least for 2 more characters: E.g. 'MikaEU' should become 'Mika EU' and not 'Mika E U'

Comment: I have added the case of consecutive letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work with Unicode and need to use Unicode categories, you should consider using [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). There, you have support for all the Unicode categories:

```
>>> import regex
>>> p = regex.compile(ur'(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})')
>>> test_str = u"Tina Turner\nMarieM\u00FCller\nJacek\u0104cki"
>>> result = p.sub(u" ", test_str)
>>> result
u'Tina Turner\nMarie M\xfcller\nJacek \u0104cki'
      ^             ^                ^
```

Here, the `(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})` regex finds all locations between the lower- (`\p{Ll}`) and uppercase (`\p{Lu}`) letters, and then the `regex.sub` inserts a space there. Note that regex module automatically compiles the regex with `regex.UNICODE` flag if the pattern is a Unicode string (`u`-prefixed).

Answer (score 2):

**It won't work for extended character**

You can use `re.sub()` for this. It will be much simpler

```
(?=(?!^)[A-Z])
```

*For handling spaces*

```
print re.sub(r'(?<=[^\s])(?=(?!^)[A-Z])', ' ', '   Tina Turner'.strip())
```

**For handling cases of consecutive capital letters**

```
print re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', '   TinaTXYurner'.strip())
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/PuhFx5)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?= #Lookahead to find all the position of capital letters
 (?!^) #Ignore the first capital letter for substitution
 [A-Z]
)
```

Comment: This won't work if a name starts with an extended character, e.g. [`Ącki`](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6bD8/1).

Comment: And it will insert a space before every uppercase ASCII letter, even if there already is one.

Comment: It does not leave subsequent capital letters intact (e.g. "abCD" becomes "ab C D" instead of "ab CD" as requested).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am having no clue about unicode..i am not even able to take down the answer..you can write your own answer for this till then I am figuring out something

Answer (score 0):

Using a function constructed of Python's string operations instead of regular expressions, this should work:

```
def split_combined_words(combined):
    separated = [combined[1]]
    for letter in combined[1:]:
        print letter
        if (letter.islower() or (letter.isupper() and separated[-1].isupper())):
            separated.append(letter)
        else:
            separated.extend((" ", letter))
    return "".join(separated)
```